# how do i divide string in part useing regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string: `123j12i need 2` I would like to split it so I end up with `123j12` and `i need 2`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$mssg = "123j12i need 2";
Preg_match("/.{6}(\d+)/", $mssg, $match);

echo $match[0];
#123j12 expected

echo $match[1];
#i need 2 expected
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post the exact expected result

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com, it'll help you build a regex string that will actually match.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
 i have edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $str = '123j12i need 2';

 $str = preg_replace('/(\w+)(\w\sneed\s[0-9])/', '\1 \2', $str);

 echo $str;
```

Outputs

```
123j12 i need 2
```

see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/40hshT/3)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$mssg = "123j12i need 2";
$match = preg_split("/(?<=123j12)/", $mssg);
var_dump($match);
```

gives

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "123j12"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "i need 2"
}
```